# text-decoration:none; being ignored in Outlook 2007

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, newsletter

Is there a way to make `text-decoration:none;` work for links in a newsletter when viewed in Outlook 2007?  I've tried inline styles in the head and body, applied directly to the anchor tags and a combination of all three.  Outlook 2007 still shows underlines for all the links regardless. Any way around it? Thanks

Answer (score 13):

This can be evaded like this:

```
<a href="#"><strong style="font-weight:normal">text here</strong></a>
```

put the text in a strong tag which is then reset to normal font weight.

Comment: a `<b>` tag is the correct semantic tag in this case, as you are not trying to deliver strong emphasis

Comment: I am confirming in 2017 that this is the only viable solution that worked for Outlook.  It utterly removes the underline from anchor links, which was the intended goal.

Comment: Wow this is something. It actually works. Why i have no idea why. Only thing i got to work for windows mail app

Answer (score 0):

My solution for Outlook 2007 is this:

```
<a href=""><span style="text-decoration:none">Text of the link</span></a>
```

But actually the code I'm using for my case is this:

```
<a href=""><strong><em><span style="text-decoration:none">Text of the link</span></em><strong></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind a `<span>` inside `<a>` tag.Use the following code snippet :

```
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"><span style="text-decoration:none;">Click Here</span></a>
```

Comment: Kindly use this :
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"><strong style="text-decoration:none;xfont-weight:normal;">Click Here</strong></a>

It works 100%

Comment: Typo? Correction: <strong style="text-decoration:none;font-weight:normal;">Click Here</strong>